# hot to add a login box only on home page?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, login, home

I'm trying to add a login box only in home page. Of course, it should disappear when a customer is logged in. So I put this layout update in the home page, but it doesn't work:

```
<customer_logged_out>
    <reference name="header">
        <block type="customer/form_login" name="header_customer_form_mini_login" template="customer/form/toplink-login-custom.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_out>
```

It works only:

```
 <reference name="header">
     <block type="customer/form_login" name="header_customer_form_mini_login" template="customer/form/toplink-login-custom.phtml"/>
  </reference>
```

But, of course, the box is shown when the customer is logged too.

Comment: Put your code  into the question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the case in which it works:

```
<reference name="header">
    <block type="customer/form_login" name="header_customer_form_mini_login" template="customer/form/toplink-login-custom.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

and just edit the template `customer/form/toplink-login-custom.phtml` and wrap its contents in an if statement that checks if the customer is logged in or not.

```
<?php if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) : ?>
    <!-- your template here -->
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: worked thanks. In your opinion, why the first code does not work at all?

Comment: @AntonioPedicini. The first approach did not work because you cannot add layout handles in a cms page layout update field. You can only add or remove blocks. The layout handle used for the homepage is `<cms_index_index>`. What you add in the backend gets appended to this layout handle and you cannot have layout handles inside other layout handles.

Comment: thanks, shall I use an update handle in that case?

Answer (score 0):

What I did was write a block with a login form then `echo` it in a hidden div if 
`Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() == false`
And then I make it pop up using Flexslider.

Answer (score 0):

Try to approach that another way. Let's add the block, but when customer is logged in – then remove it.

Go to your app/design/frontend/THEME/THEME/layout/customer.xml

Find section responsible for layouting page when customer is logged in and add remove attribute.

```
<customer_logged_in>
    <remove name="header_customer_form_mini_login"></remove>
</customer_logged_in>
```